# Journey email not sending due to AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a journey called Trade confirmation (Quoted).  I built a custom object called Quoted. It has fields:

- Account_Name__c
- Channel__c
- Created__c
- Quote_Value__c
- Trade_Confirmation__c
- Trade_Confirmation_URL__c

Here is my AMPscript:

```
%%[

/*Lookup Quoted__c Object*/
set @quotedRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Quoted__c:Id","Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation_URL__c", "Id", "=", "Quoted__c:Id")
set @quotedRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Quoted__c",)

if @quotedRowCount > 0 then
   set @tradeConfirmationURL = field(row(@quotedRows,1),"Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation_URL__c")
 endif

]%%
```

Getting this error message:

> The function call does not include the minimum number of parameters
>   required for the function Function Call:
>   RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Quoted__c",) Function Name:
>   RetrieveSalesforceObjects Number of Required Parameters: 5 Number of
>   Parameters in Call: 1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a stray code fragment in there.  Plus your lookup value needs to be a variable, not a literal string.  I'd try something like this:

```
%%[

var @id, @row
set @id = AttributeValue("Quoted__c:Id")

set @quotedRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
                    "Quoted__c"
                    , "Id, Trade_Confirmation_URL__c"
                    , "Id", "=", @id)

set @quotedRowCount = rowcount(@quotedRows)

if @quotedRowCount > 0 then

   set @row = row(@quotedRows,1)
   set @tradeConfirmationURL = field(@row,"Trade_Confirmation_URL__c")

endif

]%%
<br>tradeConfirmationURL: %%=v(@tradeConfirmationURL)=%%
```

**Reference**

- [RetrieveSalesforceObject](https://ampscript.guide/book/?section=retrievesalesforceobjects)

Comment: I got this error message .       Call to retrieve records for salesforceobject Quoted__c:Id failed! Error in the application. API Fault: Salesforce.com Fault thrown. Exception Type:InvalidSObjectFault Exception Code:INVALID_TYPE Exception Message:sObject type 'Quoted__c:Id' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. At row:-1 and column: -1

Comment: What if I am just trying to get the Quoted Object and just want to look at Trade_Confirmation_URL__C and Trade_Confirmation__c and nothing else.

Comment: The function call includes an invalid number of repeating parameters. Repeating parameters must be included in full sets.
 Function Call: RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Quoted__c:Id", "Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation_URL__c","Quoted__c:Trade_Confirmation__c", "Quoted__c:Channel__c", "Id", "=", @id)
 Function Name: RetrieveSalesforceObjects
 Number of Parameters in Repeating Set: 3
 Number of Repeating Parameters in Call: 5
 Number of Invalid Repeating Parameters in Call: 2

Comment: Ah, yes.  Updated my example.  Removed the object prefixes.